# How to use FormatMessage c++ for getting english only messages

Tags: winapi, locale

I am trying to use format message to obtain English only values

MSDN specifies the following

```
DWORD WINAPI FormatMessage(
  _In_      DWORD dwFlags,
  _In_opt_  LPCVOID lpSource,
  _In_      DWORD dwMessageId,
  _In_      DWORD dwLanguageId,
  _Out_     LPTSTR lpBuffer,
  _In_      DWORD nSize,
  _In_opt_  va_list *Arguments
);
```

For dwLanguageId parameter,

> The language identifier for the requested message. This parameter is ignored if dwFlags includes FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_STRING.
>
> If you pass a specific LANGID in this parameter, FormatMessage will return a message for that LANGID only. If the function cannot find a message for that LANGID, it sets Last-Error to ERROR_RESOURCE_LANG_NOT_FOUND. If you pass in zero, FormatMessage looks for a message for LANGIDs in the following order:
>
> 1. Language neutral
> 2. Thread LANGID, based on the thread's locale value
> 3. User default LANGID, based on the user's default locale value
> 4. System default LANGID, based on the system default locale value
> 5. US English
>
> If FormatMessage does not locate a message for any of the preceding LANGIDs, it returns any language message string that is present. If that fails, it returns ERROR_RESOURCE_LANG_NOT_FOUND.

Would this mean that, if is pass value 5, it will return messages in English?

Can you please clarify this?

Comment: This is one where I really wish I could cast an upvote specifically for the editing. Nicely done @RobKennedy!

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want just english? Surely a user should be able to read in their own language if the message is available?

Comment: that is true, but application displays all messages in English but system messages are displayed in native... making it consistent

Comment: @NidaSahar On non-english systems, for many error codes english error messages are not available, while native language messages are available for the same error codes

Comment: @CITBL, not sure what you are referring to, i had found my answer. you can refer below

Comment: @NidaSahar I recently tried to call `FormatMessage` on a Russian Windows XP, with `dwLanguageId` set to the default language. The error code was 0x1F. `FormatMessage` returned me an error message in Russian. Then I tried to use `MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US)` with the same error code. It returned me nothing. I don't think non-english systems have error messages in both languages. Well, maybe they have, but for a very limited number of error codes

Comment: I have run into the same issues, depends on what .dll the error message is coming rom, incase the wrong .dll is initialized then the appropriate error message will not be converted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The number 5 in the documentation indicates that U.S. English is the fifth language `FormatMessage` will try to use when you pass zero as the parameter value, after it has tried and failed the previous four options. That has nothing to do with passing the value `5` for that function parameter.

To request an English message, pass in the LANGID value for U.S. English, which you can get with `MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US)`. The `FormatMessage` documentation links to [documentation on language identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318691.aspx), which in turn links to a page of [language identifier constants and strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318693.aspx).

Comment: (late comment, I know..) Do you know if it's guaranteed english language error messages are available on localized systems?

Comment: No idea, @Peter. Ask a question on Stack Overflow.